# Retrieve data from Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I had a dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu(on two separate hard drives) that worked fine until I had to reinstall Windows 7.  After the install I was unable to access the Ubuntu OS.  I just need to know is it possible to get the data from the Ubuntu drive like you can with a Windows drive?  I can plug up the drive with Windows, open the desired folders and copy/move the data somewhere else.

Comment: the drive is still untouched? than you will probably manage just booting up from a live cd, mounting the drive.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but with dedicated software. Windows Explorer can't read `ext4` filesystem.

You may try [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/).

> Features Ext2Fsd supports:
>
> 1. ext2/ext3 volume reading & writing
> 2. ext3 journal replay when mounting
> 3. various codepage: utf8, cp936, cp950 …
> 4. mountpoint automatical assignment
> 5. large inode size: 128, 256, …
> 6. large file size bigger than 4G
> 7. CIFS sharing over network
> 8. htree directory indexing
> 9. **ext4 extent read-only**, no  size truncating and expanding support
> 10. Fast fsck (uninit_bg) and group block checksum support
> 11. 64k block-size, support **compatible to Linux ext4** and e2fsprogs
> 12. OS: 2k, xp, vista, server 2003/2008, win7

From http://www.ext2fsd.com/